# jQueryMobile, PhoneGap and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have already built my web pages using jQueryMobile and ASP.NET MVC framework. Now, I need to publish it to the app store using PhoneGap. I read somewhere that PhoneGap only supports HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Does that mean it will not accept my ASP.NET pages?

UPDATE 1:

If I am using plain HTML pages and invoking web services using jQuery $.ajax function then how would I make sure that the head section of the page is loaded once. I mean when using HTML only pages how can I create master pages architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.asp` pages will have to be hosted remotely from the app. You can however make AJAX calls out to the `.asp` pages from your app. to retrieve data from your server (same-domain policies do not apply in this situation so you can make AJAX calls to any domain you would like). Like on most desktop computers, mobile devices will not be able to parse `.asp` scripts as there is no interpreter for the language running on the device.

An Example:

```
$('#homepage_id').bind('pagecreate', function () {
    $.get('http://path.to.server/and/file.asp', function (data) {
        $('#homepage_id').find('[data-role="content"]').html(data);
    });
});
```

Note: the example above would require outputting valid HTML markup from the script running on your server however it is better most of the time to output JSON from the server and parse it into valid HTML markup within your JavaScript code.

**UPDATE 1:**

I would include all the necessary JavaScript functionality in the application's index page and use callback functions for your AJAX calls to "enhance" the code being gathered from your web service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have added an additional question in my original question.

Comment: What .asp files dude? You're lost! ASP.NET MVC != ancient ASP

Comment: @DotNetWise I'm unfamiliar with any ASP languages. `.aspx`, is that right? And does it change the answer I provided (seems like no since mobile devices still won't be able to parse it)?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC does not have .aspx "pages" as you might think. Instead .aspx/.cshtml views that are returned/rendered by the controllers.
So you can't just export the views for PhoneGap to use!

Comment: @DotNetWise I lost you at " So you can't just export the views for PhoneGap to use!"  I don't know what you mean, but you should be able to run PhoneGap JavaScript functions inside of MVC views.

Comment: Yes, you can run the scripts :)
You just need to somehow save the HTML output and send it to Phonegap.

Comment: the new web api provides great improvements to this through a restul interface

Answer (score -6):

Anyone reading this thread might want to consider dropping .NET MVC and just using static .htm files. You can call your .NET code through a simple .ashx file that can be accessed through jQuery. Pass XML or JSON and get back a generic Dataset object. I've been doing this for years and it gives me a great workaround when I need quick solutions. I don't even bother with middle tier code anymore, prefering instead to put all of my business rules in SQL Server stored procs, highly-recommended, and works GREAT with mobile platforms like PhoneGap.

Comment: Highly **unrecommended**. Modifying such monolithic solutions in the future is a nightmare.